# AngularJS: On GetJSON complete use the data in other controller

Tags: angularjs

I'm newbie in Angular.

```
// This is my main controller
app.controller('AppCtrl', ['$rootScope', '$scope', 'cfpLoadingBar', '$http',
function ($rootScope, $scope, cfpLoadingBar, $http) {

    cfpLoadingBar.start();

    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function (event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {

        //stop loading bar on stateChangeSuccess
        event.targetScope.$watch("$viewContentLoaded", function () {

            // HERE I want to send request to API and on complete do
            // 1. Complete loadbar
            // 2. Write response to global var and use it from other controller
            $http.get(
              '/api/',
              {}
            ).then(function (response) {

                // Completing loadbar
                cfpLoadingBar.complete();

                $SOME_GLOBAL_VAR.api = response;


            });


        });

    });

}]);


// Controller 1
app.controller('Ctrl_1', ["$scope", "$http" function ($scope, $http) {
    $scope.param = 'get_data_1';

    When $SOME_GLOBAL_VAR.api
    console.log($SOME_GLOBAL_VAR.api);

}]);
```

I want to use one api request for different controllers.
So I want to load API, and when it finish - each controller will render his part.
Now I can't understand how to listen to API loading is completed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this in following way

```
$http.get(
      '/api/',
      {}
).then(function (response) {

        // Completing loadbar
        cfpLoadingBar.complete();

        $rootScope.$emit("receivedApiUpdate", response);


});



angular.module("my_module")('controller1', ['$rootScope', function($rootScope) {
    $rootScope.$on('receivedApiUpdate',function(event, response){
        // Do your work
    });
}]);

angular.module("my_module")('controller2', ['$rootScope', function($rootScope) {
    $rootScope.$on('receivedApiUpdate',function(event, response){
        // Do your work
    });
}]);

angular.module("my_module")('controller3', ['$rootScope', function($rootScope) {
    $rootScope.$on('receivedApiUpdate',function(event, response){
        // Do your work
    });
}]);
```

Comment: This helps me! Thnk you!

Answer (score 1):

you can try to make a service and use your service across your controllers.

https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services